# How do i execute queries and fetch data from the result in ZEND 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to execute queries in zend2 in a old fashion way. I want to write queries and execute it. I do not want to use the function save(), update(), delete().
This is my model:

```
namespace Application\Model;
    
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\ResultInterface;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
    
class UsersTable extends AbstractTableGateway {
    
    public function __construct(Adapter $adapter) {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
    }
    
    public function fetchAll() {    
        $results  = $this->adapter->query("SELECT * FROM users");
        return $results->execute();
    }
}
```

In the function fetchAll I want to execute the query "select * from users". How can i do that ?
The result of this is :

```
object(Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result)#243 (8) {
  ["statementMode":protected]=>
  string(7) "forward"
  ["resource":protected]=>
  object(PDOStatement)#241 (1) {
    ["queryString"]=>
    string(19) "SELECT * FROM users"
  }
  ["options":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["currentComplete":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["currentData":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["position":protected]=>
  int(-1)
  ["generatedValue":protected]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["rowCount":protected]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: I guess its a hard question :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will make an Array

```
public function fetchAll() {
    $stmt = $this->adapter->query('SELECT * FROM user');
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    if($result->count() > 0) {
        $returnArr = array();
        while ($result->valid()) {
            $returnArr[] = $result->current();
            $result->next();
        }
        if(count($returnArr) > 0) {
            return $returnArr;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: what does the current function do ? I just don;t get it why I need it ? thxx

Comment: What do you want? This function give you the content from table user as Array.

Comment: "You can avoid the foreach loop by doing the following": See last but one answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107346/zend-framework-2-db-adapter-adapter-query-resultset-like-zf1 . Using this answer you are making an extra loop, so it's not the best practice.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of looping the resultset and calling next(), you can do the following:

```
public function fetchAll() {
    $results  = $this->adapter->query("SELECT * FROM users");
    $result = $results->execute();
    return $result->getResource()->fetchAll();
}
```

The function will return the data as an array.

Comment: `fetchAll()` is a PDO function. In another case it may not exist!?

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row){
    $row->column1
    $row->column2
}
```

OR

```
$result = $result->toArray();
```